# PHP MySql json encoding array

Tags: php, mysql

So I'm having a weird issue. When I the database and attempt to store it in an array that is json encoded, then returned to the website, it only works when the array is strictly less than 40 rows. The code below results in a successful post, but the data returned is empty (i.e. `data.data = ""`).

EDIT: Forgot to mention, this is running on WampServer x64 3.0.6

javascript

```
$http.post('api/procedures/members_get.php', "members_get", { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'} }).then(
  function(data){
    $scope.members = data.data;
  });
```

members_get.php

```
<?php
include '../config.php';

if(ISSET($_POST['members_get'])) {
  $conn = mysqli_connect(DB_HOST, DB_USERNAME, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

  $result = $conn->query("SELECT memberid AS id, firstname, lastname, status FROM members__details ORDER BY lastname ASC");

  $arr = array();
  while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $arr[] = $row
  }

  $conn->close();

  $json_response = json_encode($arr);
  echo $json_response;
}
```

Confusingly, if I modify the code to first json encode each row before being added to the array, and then decoding each row in the array, it returns all the rows correctly.

```
...
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $arr[] = json_encode($row);
}

foreach ($arr as &$value) {
  $value = json_decode($value);
}
unset($value);
...
```

This code is extremely inefficient and unnecessary. This is a bad hack, and I'd like to know why the `$arr` array doesn't return properly if there are more than 39 rows (of course the 39 rows is probably a magic number, but regardless this is not the correct behavior).

EDIT: The problem was there was a utf-8 character `ß` in row 40 of the database (Suprise!). I just need to make sure the php file follows UTF-8 standard.

Comment: It may be something about the data on the 40th row of the database.  Check for quotes etc. in the data.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a unicode character within the database. I solved this by using `utf8_encode` on the values in the row before adding it to the array.

```
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
  $row = array_map('utf8_encode', $row);
  $arr[] = $row;
}
```